# Zoomable D3 TreeMap (d3-v5)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I used [this](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/treemap_basic.html) example to render a treemap and made customization changes wrt colors etc.
Now the latest requirement is to make the treemap zoomable/drilldown. I found another example [here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-treemap).

What changes do I have to make to the eariler example to make it drill down (they don't want me to rework and customize again)

Any small hint would be appreciated as well.

Here's the code from the example I used

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
  width = 445 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 445 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Read data
d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/data_hierarchy_1level.csv', function(data) {

  // stratify the data: reformatting for d3.js
  var root = d3.stratify()
    .id(function(d) { return d.name; })   // Name of the entity (column name is name in csv)
    .parentId(function(d) { return d.parent; })   // Name of the parent (column name is parent in csv)
    (data);
  root.sum(function(d) { return +d.value })   // Compute the numeric value for each entity

  // Then d3.treemap computes the position of each element of the hierarchy
  // The coordinates are added to the root object above
  d3.treemap()
    .size([width, height])
    .padding(4)
    (root)

console.log(root.leaves())
  // use this information to add rectangles:
  svg
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x0; })
      .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y0; })
      .attr('width', function (d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
      .attr('height', function (d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("fill", "#69b3a2");

  // and to add the text labels
  svg
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x0+10})    // +10 to adjust position (more right)
      .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y0+20})    // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.name})
      .attr("font-size", "15px")
      .attr("fill", "white")
})
```

Comment: which d3js version are you using? also adding your code here might help addressing your issue.

Comment: I'm using d3-v5. Added the code as well